# How to use text/template's predefined "call" function?

Tags: go, template-engine

I'm trying to understand how to use `call` function in `text/template` package. Here is example:

```
type Human struct {
    Name string
}

func (h *Human) Say(str string) string {
    return str
}

func main() {
    const letter = `
    {{.Name}} wants to say {{"blabla" | .Say}}
    {{.Name}} wants try again, {{call .Say "blabla"}}.`

    var h = &Human{"Tim"}

    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(letter))
    err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, h)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("executing template:", err)
    }

}
```

[see this code in play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/ajpat2zFfS)

I thought that `call` calls functions/methods, but as it turned out we can do it just by `.Method arg1 arg2`. So what is function `call` intended for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `call` if you want to call a function value.

To quote the [docs](https://godoc.org/text/template) (See under Functions):

> Thus "call .X.Y 1 2" is, in Go notation, dot.X.Y(1, 2) where  Y is a
>   func-valued field, map entry, or the like.

In this example `X` could look like this:

```
type X struct {
    Y func(a int, b int) int
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it tells me nothing. I've read it 3 times.. could you give an example? What does it mean "function value"?

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov Added an example of how X could look like.

Answer (score 1):

https://play.golang.org/p/usia3d8STOG

```
    type X struct {
        Y func(a int, b int) int
    }
    x := X{Y: func(a int, b int) int {
        return a + b
    }}
    tmpl, err := template.New("test").Parse(`{{call .X.Y 1 2}}
    `)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, map[string]interface{}{"X": x})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```